# Integrate with substitution

Tags: integration

Use the substitution $x=2\sin(\theta)$ to find the value of

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{(4+x^2)^{3/2}}dx$$

I got to $$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{2\cos(\theta)}{(4+4\cos^2(\theta))^{3/2}}d\theta.$$
However, I don't know how to further integrate this!

Thanks!

Comment: The substitution $x=2\sin(\theta)$ is more appropriate for something of the form $4-x^2$. Try substituting $x=2\tan(x)$ instead, which works better for $4+x^2$, because you can convert $4+4\tan^2(\theta) = 4\sec^2(\theta)$.

Comment: The textbook question asked me to use 2sin(theta) as the substitution But I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: It could be a typo in the book. Honestly, $x=2\sin(\theta)$ is not a good choice here. Using $x=2\tan(\theta)$ will change the integral to simply the integral of $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Okay, I tried to use x=2tan(theta) , getting the integral of ln|secx| / 2secx. Where do i go from here?

Comment: Sorry was using the wrong identity. It is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now let's perform the indefinite integral: $$\int \frac{1}{(4+x^2)^{3/2}}dx.$$

If we use the substitution $x=2\tan(\theta)$ this gives $dx=2\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$.

Plugging in the subsitution yields: $$\int \frac{2\sec^2(\theta)}{(4+4\tan^2(\theta))^{3/2}} d\theta=\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\sec^3(\theta)} d\theta =\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{\sec(\theta)}d\theta =\frac{1}{4} \int \cos(\theta)d\theta =\frac{1}{4} \sin(\theta)+C.$$

Since $x/2 = \tan(\theta)$, this means $$\sin(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}.$$

Comment: This works, It turns out that the book had a typo. I found the exam paper where it originated from and it was 4-x^2. However, this solution seems to work as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your denominator is not correct. It should be $(4+4(sinθ)^2)^{3/2}=8(1+sin^2θ)^{3/2}$. Can you solve the integral now?

Comment: Are you sure this simplication is possible? [link]http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%284%2B4%28sin%CE%B8%29%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%3D8%281%2Bsin2%CE%B8%29%5E%283%2F2%29+true+or+false

Comment: @Tomato721, e_f_i is pointing out that you accidentally wrote $(4+4\cos^2(\theta))$ in the denominator when you meant to write $4+4\sin^2(\theta)$. Remember, you were replacing $x$ with $2\sin(\theta)$ and not $2\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Yeah my bad, However, is the simplification he did possible?